# Electronjs Screenshare ,Keyboard ,copy paste restrictions

Tags: javascript, electron

When attempting to capture a screenshot in a web application developed with ElectronJS, the resulting image shows a black screen. Additionally, standard actions like copy-paste commands and keyboard shortcuts do not seem to function as expected .Applications like teamviewer, google meet, teams gives black screen. i can only use autotyper

I attempted to modify the settings of the app.asar package, including contextIsolation, nodeIntegration, kiosk, and web security settings. However, these changes resulted in the application failing to open